# Unable to login or reset password in Strapi Production Admin

Tags: strapi

## First off

> I use a password manager called 1 password that even lest's me look at deleted passwords. This is significant because I can say with confidence that I haven't lost my password, I used the same password as I did on my development server for the strapi admin pannel. The password works in development but is not working in production. even weirder is that the password reset functionality isn't working. I have tried every email possible and I haven't received any emails.

### My big question

If this isn't some weird glitch in the strapi system... That means the only other possibility is that someone spent a lot of time and effort to hack into my admin pannel in order to gain absolutley nothing, but changing my email to inconveinience me. **Please lmk if anyone else is expeiriencing login troubles or if you have any tips on how I should proceed.** Right now I feel like I really should get in touch with someone at Strapi because this could be a major issue if someone actually cared about the data that would be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The easiest solution I found:

#### Important: You will lose all your data if you do this method

> The easiest solution is to restart your production database. If you click on the project database in Heroku there is an option to restart it. After doing that you will be able to create a new production user.